# Deploy natively from one platform to multiple platforms - JavaFX 2.2

Tags: deployment, javafx-2, javafx

JavaFX 2.2 now includes a "nativebundles" attribute on its deploy method which is very convenient to provide native packages of your application to multiple platforms. However, it only builds native packages for the current platform.

Is there a way to expand its functionality so it can built from one system, for all platforms? Even if it's just possible from, say, Windows to build for a subset of other native systems that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "nativebundles" attribute produces [Self-Contained Application Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1307236), for which the JavaFX 2.x documention says:

> Self-contained application packages are platform specific and can only be produced for the same system that you build on. If you want to deliver self-contained application packages on Windows, Linux and Mac you will have to build your project on all three platforms.

If you don't want to use multiple physical machines, then you will need to build in virtual machines.  Something free like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) could be installed on your development or build machine with VM instances for your target OSes.  If your development machine is a Mac, then you can install two VM instances, one for Windows and one for Linux to build to those target platforms.  If your development machine is Linux or Windows, then you may need to get access to a Mac machine to create a Mac specific build.  Also be careful of 32 bit vs 64 bit builds.  You may want to generate further packages if you want to distribute both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of your software and you won't be able to do that from a 32 bit operating system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's supported in JavaFX 2.2.

There's a feature request for that.

Please see RT-22994: Native installers - provide a way to build all installers for all OS's on one OS. 
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22994